# How to set the monitor refresh rate for a playwright test?

Tags: google-chrome, playwright

I have a program that renders something to a Canvas using WebGL and JavaScript's `requestAnimationFrame`.

I am building a benchmark test that I want to test on different computers under various screen sizes and refresh-rates: for example, modern macbooks have 120fps screens, but most external monitors would be 30-60fps. Depending on the display where Chrome is rendered, it picks the refresh rate to match the display.

I am using playwright to run this test in headless mode on various devices and CI. You can set the screen size and zoom level [according to the docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browser#browser-new-context-option-screen), but there is nothing about the refresh rate.

How to set or limit the refresh rate for Playwright? I am using Playwright with Chromium.

Comment: this is not possibe as at Jan-2023. It might be added in later playwright version